# asp.net vb replace string in string and make it bold

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, replace

I'm looking for an function to replace a string in a string and only make it bold. I already got this function:

```
Function MakeBold(ByVal input As String, ByVal find As String) As String
    Return Regex.Replace(input, find, "<strong>" + find + "</strong>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
End Function
```

This works but it removes the capital of a string. For example if i would run it with the string "Lorem ipsum dolor sit Dolor" and the replace part to be "dolor", it will return "Lorem ipsum **dolor** sit **dolor**". The second "dolor" loses it capital cause it's being replaced with one without a capital. How can i keep capitals in my string? So for example "DoLoR" will also still be that and not "dolor"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Function MakeBold(ByVal input As String, ByVal find As String) As String
    Return Regex.Replace(input, find, "<strong>$0</strong>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
End Function
```

The `$0` in the replace-pattern is subsituted with the full match.

See also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

hello what about this function:

```
Private Function MakeBold(allstring As String, toFind As String) As String
    Return allstring.Replace(toFind, [String].Format("<strong>{0}</strong>", toFind))
  End Function
```

Comment: Your code ignores words with different capitalization, Johan wants to replace those also while keeping the original capitalization.